# Unauthorized error setting batch-bigtable as data host from Spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, spark-streaming, google-cloud-bigtable, spark-streaming-kafka

I'm following the example here for writing to Cloud Bigtable from Spark Streaming: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/scala/spark-streaming

In my instance, I'm consuming from Kafka, doing some transformations, then need to write them to my Bigtable instance. Initially, using all the dependency versions from that example, I was getting UNAUTHORIZED errors from timeouts when trying to access anything from Bigtable past connecting:

```
Refreshing the OAuth token Retrying failed call. Failure #1, got: Status{code=UNAUTHENTICATED, description=Unexpected failure get auth token,
cause=java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205) 
at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.io.RefreshingOAuth2CredentialsInterceptor.getHeader(RefreshingOAuth2CredentialsInterceptor.java:290)
```

I then bumped the `bigtable-hbase-1.x-hadoop` dependency to something more recent, like 1.9.0, and get through the authentication for the table admin work, but then get an additional UNAUTHORIZED when actually trying to make the `saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset()` call:

```
Retrying failed call. Failure #1, got: Status{code=UNAUTHENTICATED, description=Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. 
See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project., cause=null} on channel 34. 
Trailers: Metadata(www-authenticate=Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/",bigtable-channel-id=34)
```

I've found that removing the `conf.set(BigtableOptionsFactory.BIGTABLE_HOST_KEY, BigtableOptions.BIGTABLE_BATCH_DATA_HOST_DEFAULT)` from the `setBatchConfigOptions()` method allows the call to authenticate with the default host fine, and will process several Kafka messages, but then stalls, hangs up and eventually throws a `No route to host` error:

```
019-07-25 17:29:12 INFO JobScheduler:54 - Added jobs for time 1564093750000 ms 
2019-07-25 17:29:21 INFO JobScheduler:54 - Added jobs for time 1564093760000 ms 
2019-07-25 17:29:31 INFO JobScheduler:54 - Added jobs for time 1564093770000 ms 
2019-07-25 17:29:36 WARN OperationAccountant:116 - No operations completed within the last 30 seconds. There are still 1 operations in progress. 
2019-07-25 17:29:36 WARN OperationAccountant:116 - No operations completed within the last 30 seconds. There are still 1 operations in progress. 
2019-07-25 17:29:36 WARN OperationAccountant:116 - No operations completed within the last 30 seconds. There are still 1 operations in progress. 
2019-07-25 17:29:36 WARN OperationAccountant:116 - No operations completed within the last 30 seconds. There are still 1 operations in progress. 
2019-07-25 17:29:36 WARN OperationAccountant:116 - No operations completed within the last 30 seconds. There are still 1 operations in progress. 
2019-07-25 17:29:36 WARN OperationAccountant:116 - No operations completed within the last 30 seconds. There are still 1 operations in progress. 
2019-07-25 17:29:36 WARN OperationAccountant:116 - No operations completed within the last 30 seconds. There are still 1 operations in progress. 
2019-07-25 17:29:36 WARN OperationAccountant:116 - No operations completed within the last 30 seconds. There are still 1 operations in progress. 
2019-07-25 17:29:38 WARN AbstractRetryingOperation:130 - Retrying failed call. 
Failure #1, got: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=io exception, cause=com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedNoRouteToHostException: No route to host: batch-bigtable.googleapis.com/2607:f8b0:400f:801:0:0:0:200a:443
```

I'm assuming this is an issue with dependency versions since that example is fairly old, but can't find any newer examples of writing to Bigtable from Spark Streaming. I haven't had any luck finding version combinations that work with `bigtable-hbase-2.x-hadoop`.

Current POM:

```
<scala.version>2.11.0</scala.version>
<spark.version>2.3.3</spark.version>
<hbase.version>1.3.1</hbase.version>
<bigtable.version>1.9.0</bigtable.version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>26.0-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.74.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigtable</groupId>
        <artifactId>bigtable-hbase-2.x-hadoop</artifactId>
        <version>${bigtable.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-bigtable</artifactId>
        <version>0.95.0-alpha</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Where are you running this? The example is geared towards Google Cloud Dataproc which runs workers as GCE instances which provide authentication through the metadata server. The no route to host error is towards an IPv6 address, which would not work on GCE.

Comment: This is running locally out of IntelliJ IDEA, but also gets the same error when running off my local Spark installation using spark-submit. 

Edit: The authentication issue was a known issue in the current build and a new bigtable version, 1.12.0, was released last week that solved that issue. Now I'm just seeing the "no route to host" exception, when running in batch or default. I'll try setting up a dataproc job and seeing if that solves it, but being able to run locally would be nice.

Comment: I was able to verify that when running out of Dataproc, everything works correctly. Only when running locally does it throw the NoRouteToHostException.

Comment: It was a corporate firewall issue. I just had to set the -Dhttps.proxyHost and -Dhttps.proxyPort system properties when running locally. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authentication issues with batch mode were a known issue in the Bigtable API. They recently released 1.12.0 which addressed these issues. The NoRouteToHostException was isolated to running locally, and ended up being a corporate firewall issue which resolved when setting -Dhttps.proxyHost and -Dhttps.proxyPort.